# Embedding image breaks javascript in RMarkdown presentation

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

The following turns out fine.

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: ioslides_presentation
---

## forceNetwork

```{r, echo = FALSE}
library(networkD3)
data(MisLinks)
data(MisNodes)
forceNetwork(Links = MisLinks, Nodes = MisNodes, Source = "source",
             Target = "target", Value = "value", NodeID = "name",
             Group = "group", opacity = 0.4)
```

## word cloud

```{r echo = FALSE, warning = FALSE}
library(wordcloud)
wordcloud(c(letters, LETTERS, 0:9), seq(1, 1000, len = 62))
```
````

However, if I switch the order of the slides, i.e. word cloud first, the js visualization doesn't show up.

**EDIT:**
I found out that if I refresh the page, the graphics show up. Why does this happen?

Comment: caching in your browser? If it can't be reproduced, then it can't be diagnosed.